# Core Data Displaying Attributes Individually From Log

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

so I have been trying to use Core Data with a logbook app that records information. In this case it is flying hours. So I input data and it uses Core Data to save/store is as a set value but I have only made it display a small amount of the saved info in the table view(see in code below).

What I need help with, it making it so I can click on each tableViewCell which goes to a VC where it has all the info which the user inputted into the app(as it is a logbook)

How will it be possible so that the user will see their specific info for that specific cell which have different info stored as they are all different logs

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return logArray.count
}
//WHATS IN THE TABLE VIEW CELL FUNCTION/////
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) 
    let log = logArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = "Flight:" + "  " + log.date! + "      Click For More Info -->"
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create variable for log in your `UITableViewCell`

```
var log: Log?
```

now in `cellForRowAt` set log of cell independent on `indexPath.row`

```
cell.log = logArray[indexPath.row]
```

then create variable in second ViewController.

```
var selectedLog: Log?
```

Now in Table View delegate method `didSelectRowAt`perform segue with sender as that cell

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier", sender: tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath))
}
```

And finally in prepare for segue method declare destination ViewController as YourSecondViewController and set its selectedLogProperty

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier" {
         let destinationVC = segue.destination as! YourSecond ViewController
         let senderCell = sender as! YourTableViewCell
         destinationVC.selectedLog = senderCell.log!
    }
}
```

Comment: @RileyLunz :-) If it helped, you could accept my answer